# Can I put a single word before my indent?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm working on a movie script. I'm having some issues with my indents...

All the spoken text is outlined to the left, but I want the name of the speakers to be in front of this paragraph. The name of the speaker and the text itself are in the same text field.

It should look like this:
[image]

Because I can't make a paragraph style and apply it only to the name of the speaker I have to come up with something else..

How can I move a single word a bit backwards, and keep the rest of the paragraph outlined on the indent I chose?

Hope someone can help me..

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a negative first line indent in the **Paragraph Panel**.

[image]

Make *that* a Paragraph Style.

If you want the name bolder, set that using a *Character* style.